# android ArrayList and draw without for loop

Tags: android

Can I call a function in ArrayList without having to use a for loop or is there a anthoer way of doing this I hope my example will make more sense.

```
   public class Fireball {

      public void draw(GL10 gl){
         draw(gl);
      }

public class Gameview {

   private ArrayList<FireBall> fireBall = new ArrayList<FireBall>();

   public draw(GL10 gl){
     //this is where I what to draw everthing in the ArrayList
       fireBall.getIndex(ALL).draw(gl)
    }
}
```

the reason I am asking is because I what to be able to add and remove fireball without having to worry about the computer speed thank you

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through an `ArrayList` is not that cpu-consuming (although using vectors you could optimize even more), and even if you had a method of drawing multiple fireballs at once, that method would still iterate through the `ArrayList` just as you would.

Comment: Why would a Vector be faster than an ArrayList? If anything, is it not the other way around (because Vector has synchronization overhead)?

Comment: ah sorry, by vector i meant Fireball[].  Edit: I only now realized that what my professor called "vector" everybody else calls an "array" ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an arraylist, you could use a while loop.
Just check is the contents of the list isn't null

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("a");
al.add("b");
al.add("c");
al.add("d");
al.add("e");

int counter = 1;
while (!al.isEmpty()) {
   System.out.println(counter++ + ": " + al.toString());
   al.remove(0);
}
```

Output:

> 1: [a, b, c, d, e]
>   2: [b, c, d, e]
>   3: [c, d, e]
>   4: [d, e]
>   5: [e]

Advantage is that it uses less memory, since your deleting unused elements, but if you want to reuse the arraylist, you should just loop through the elements:

```
fireball.getIndex(ALL);
while (Fireball f : fireball) {
     f.draw(gl)
}
```